Map Data Visualisation in Tableau
So, I want to create a map visualisation (usa map), there will be 2 layers(2 datasets)
first - when you hover on a state, so information will appear in a table format.
second - organizations will appear in states as dots, and when you click on these dots, the org info will be displayed in a table format
The issue right now, is that the data isn't populating correctly. Some states have 2-3 organizations but, only 1 mark is showing up.
Second, not all states are populating for the first layer, and even though there are links in the source row, they aren't showing up in some states.
What is the issue here? How to fix this?
Is Tableau the right tool, or should I use something else?
Layer1
Layer 2

Tableau can create visualizations like you describe, but your question is too vague to provide specific guidance. Provide sample data, show what you've done, what you expect to see versus what actually happens, and a specific question. In that case, people can assist. Respectfully, expect to need to invest some time learning whatever mapping tool you choose too. Tableau makes such work as easy as possible, but there are still concepts to learn to use it effectively.
